# Stop notification window from stealing focus

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

In my WPF application I have a notification window that appears at the top right for 3 seconds and closes.  Just a normal notification window.

But when it appears, it takes the focus away from any window that was active.  For example, if I'm typing in Chrome and the window appears, chrome looses focus and my typing is halted.

The notification window is set to top most so that it will appear on top of other windows, but how do I go about stopping it from stealing the focus of the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [Window.ShowActivated Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showactivated.aspx) to false on your notification window.

```
var notificationWindow= new NotificationWindow{
    ShowActivated = false, Topmost = true, ShowInTaskbar = false};
notificationWindow.Show();
```

Comment: how can i do this in windows form application? as there is no ShowActivated property for windows form.